# Multiple selection in intellij-idea?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, sublimetext2

Is it possible to do multiple selections and change them at the same time like in sublimetext2 editor ([sublimetext](http://www.sublimetext.com/)) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is finally available!

> IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 introduces Sublime style multiple selections, the top voted editor feature in our tracker!

Please refer to the [Official Announcement](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/intellij-idea-13-1-rc-introduces-sublime-text) for details and examples of how it works.

Answer (score 8):

There is **column selection mode**, but it doesn't provide the same features, please vote for this request:

- [IDEA-80056](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80056) Column selection mode improvement

Comment: by the way, [this](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/phpstorm-7-early-access-program-started/#comment-2532) recently came to my attention: "Multi-cursor support is planned to be finished by IntelliJ IDEA 13 release (end-of-the-year)"

Answer (score 3):

While we wait for it to be natively implemented in the IDE, you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16130587/1306903)!

Answer (score 1):

#### Existing Hotkeys

**Windows:** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd>(Hold) + <kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd>

**Mac:** <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd>(Hold) + <kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd>.

To place caret at the end of rows: move caret to top row, clone down to bottom, and click <kbd>END</kbd>.

#### Change Multi-caret Hotkey

To add a custom Keymap, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, type `keymap` and click on the one with `Settings` as subtext. Search for `Clone Caret Above` and `Clone Caret Below`.

I mapped mine to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd> on Windows and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd> on Mac.

#### Bonus

Try holding combinations of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, and arrows for improved selection power.