# Is there a way to connect Intellij IDEA to Sublime Text on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, sublimetext2

I would like to find a way to open a file in Sublime Text 2 from Intellij IDEA (on Mac OS X), as to use its advanced text editing features on those occasions where writing "normal text" is not enough!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The following is as far as you can go, without getting your "hands dirty" with writing plugins; even so, it will open the file preserving cursor position and also add the file folder to the sidebar.

1. [Configure](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html) Sublime Text command-line tool `subl` (if you haven't already)
2. In Intellij IDEA, click on **`Intellij IDEA`** -> **`Preferences...`** [or press *CMD+,*]
3. Find **`External Tools`** (under **`IDE Settings`**)
4. Click on the plus (+) icon [or press *CTRL+N*]
5. Fill in the fields like this:

[image]

Keep in mind that in the **`Program`** field you will need to put where you installed `subl`!

**Update for Sublime Text 3**:

Assuming Sublime Text is in `/Applications`, you can use this for the **`Program`** field: `/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl`

Comment: Parameters (for copy-paste): -n -w -a "$FileDir$" "$FileName$:$LineNumber$:$ColumnNumber$"

Comment: Is there a way to have shortcut on that?

Comment: If you do not want to file opened in a **new window**, use next macros: `-a "$FileDir$" "$FileName$:$LineNumber$:$ColumnNumber$"`.

Comment: The path to subl is not unlikely to be `/usr/local/bin/subl`.

Comment: @vach, do you mean a keyboard shortcut? Just go to Preferences > Keymap, search for the name you gave it in External Tools, and give it the keyboard shortcut you want.

Comment: I can confirm that the parameters here still works as of 10.10.2022 for the Mac M1 series, tested on multiple machines, and for Sublime Text 4.