# Recorded Macros in Run/Debug configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

As the title says.

Is it possible to add a macro I have recorded in `Run/Debug configuration` and in the `Before launch` configuration?

Comment: What your `macro` should do ?

Comment: @DozortsevAnton It triggers a plugin action: `Action: antlr.Generate`

Comment: Create `External tool` that run shell script and add it in `Before launch` configuration.

Comment: @DozortsevAnton I understand the idea but I lost you on the steps. Can you please add some more info on what to write in "Create tool" window?

Comment: Check this **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16130587/2650174)** . In your case in `Program` option it's should be path to you `.sh` script.